# Recreate View in ADT

Tags: android, eclipse, constructor, adt, surfaceview

We have one MainActivity.
On this Main I would like to display my SurfaceView, but only if a button was clicked.
So when the main is started and the user clicks one button the SurfaceView should appear and everytim it appears it should excecute the onCreate-Method.

But it did not work.

All of my code is in this constructor:

```
         public GameView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
```

So this one should be usesd, but i don't know what to do :/

EDIT:

Code in XML:

```
          <de.apex.viewer.view.GameView
          android:id="@+id/gameView1"
          android:layout_width="300dp"
          android:layout_height="300dp"
          android:layout_centerInParent="true"
          android:layout_marginLeft="94dp" />
```

Here is some Code from the main:

```
         public void displayGameView(View view) 
        { // here I need code to "recreate" my gameView
        }
```

And here some Code from the GameView which should be displayed:

```
       public class GameView extends SurfaceView {

       public GameView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) 
       {
       super(context, attrs);
       surfaceHolder = getHolder();
       surfaceHolder.addCallback(new SurfaceHolder.Callback() 
       {

       public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) 
       {}

       public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) 
       {
        // here is my code I want to execute
   Canvas theCanvas = surfaceHolder.lockCanvas(null);
   HouseInRow = DefineRowCount(arraylength);
   GesamtZahl = HouseInRow*2+HouseInColumn*2;
   System.out.println("Houserow: " + HouseInRow);


       public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format,int width, int height) 
       {}
       });    
        }
```

Comment: PLease, post your code where you're initiating and adding your GameView.

Comment: `OnCreate()` method is called only once when activity or service is first appeared. You need to post more of your code for me to understand your flow exactly.

Comment: Adding GameView in XML:

Comment: When i change the Visibility of the GameView with              findViewById(R.id.gameView1).setVisibility(1); there only appear a black filled rectangle